# What does the 'free(): invalid next sign (fast)' error really mean?

Tags: c, free

Let's say I've got a program `foo` that allocates and frees memory. I run it like this:

```
./foo something.foo
```

It works perfectly, exits with no errors. Now, if I set the first line of the file to `#!/path/foo`, change the permissions, and run it as `./something.foo`, the program runs correctly, but before exiting, I see this:

```
*** Error in '/path/foo': free(): invalid next size(fast): 0x019e2008 ***
Aborted
```

I've seen a lot of questions about `free(): invalid next sign(fast)`, all with specific code examples. So I've got two questions:

- Why might the error appear when using `#!/path/foo` instead of `./foo`?
- What exactly does the error mean - what conditions must be present for it to appear?

---

Huh, fixed this by changing

```
some_var = malloc(sizeof(char *));
```

to

```
some_var = malloc(CONSTANT);
```

Comment: It means that foo has an issue with memory management or (highly unlikely) the kernel has issues in its exec() code.

Comment: If necessary, I'm running this on a Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian PIXEL.

Comment: Oh, I would have suggested Valgrind if it was running on a computer... Though sure, it's possible the ARM Linux kernel has bugs

Comment: More info - each pointer begins with `0x00` and ends with `008`. Don't know if that means anything.

Comment: 0x00 means it's early in the heap (predictible), ends with 008 due to alignment in C heap. Nothing special on that

Comment: Did you write the foo program yourself?

Comment: Oh, found more info - if I cause the program to terminate early the pointer has `0x01` at the beginning instead of `0x00`.

Comment: *... if I set the first line of the file to `#!/path/foo`, change the permissions, and run it as `./something.foo` ...*  In other words, you changed the input and got different results.  You need to post your code - it's most likely a memory corruption bug in your code.

Comment: @AndrewHenle My code is almost 2000 lines long, with over 80 calls to `free` and `malloc`...

Comment: @AndrewHenle And no, it's not all in one source file.

Comment: @Redesign All that complexity increases the chances the problem is in your code.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I'll `grep` for `free`s and `malloc`s in the code that existed when I first saw the error.

Comment: @PaulStelian The raspberry pi linux port does not have *bugs* (at least not: more than expected on a desktop/server platform)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means you have heap corruption in your program.  The message is telling you how the C library detected the corruption, not how the corruption occurred.

Heap corruption is a particularly insidious bug to track down as it generally does not manifest at the point where the bug occurs, but rather at some later point.  Its quite possible for the program to continue to work despite the corruption, meaning it might be a bug that has been present in your code for weeks or months and has nothing to do with any recent changes you are testing and debugging.

The best response to heap corruption is usually a tool like [valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org), which can run along with your program and will often (though not always) be able to pinpoint where the offending code is.